# Simple Scroll down an activity

Tags: java, xml, android-activity, scroll

Is their any simple XML and Java code that I can add to my apps pages that will let me scroll up and down the page?

Answer (score 0):

There is [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) available which handles the overflow and such. I think this was what you are looking for